# which is the class for setting width and height properties of an image in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I added an  tag inside a  tag in an HTML page. I need to set the image width and height using Bootstrap class. How can I do that? Anyone have idea?

I'm sharing my code below:

```
<div class="col">
          <div class="card border border-2 border-danger w-75 mt-3">
            <img src="/Images/oppo-a31-2020-128-gb-black-6-gb-ram-.jpg" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid" style="height:200px; width:200px;" alt="xxx">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h5 class="card-title">Oppo A13</h5>
              <p class="card-text" >Our Price: To see product details, add this item to your cart. You can always remove it later.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *OVERRIDE* Bootstrap, you need to do exactly what you're doing: add `style="height:200px; width:200px;"` to your `<img>` element.

Otherwise, for Bootstrap's "default" image styling, look here:

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/
>
> - **Responsive images**
>
>   Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. This
>   applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it
>   scales with the parent element.
> - **Image thumbnails**
>
>   In addition to our border-radius utilities, you can use
>   .img-thumbnail to give an image a rounded 1px border appearance.
> - **Aligning images**
>
> Align images with the helper float classes or text alignment classes.
> block-level images can be centered using the .mx-auto margin utility
> class.
>
> - **Sass Variables**
>
>   Variables are available for image thumbnails.
>
>   ```
>   $thumbnail-padding:                 .25rem;
>   $thumbnail-bg:                      $body-bg;
>   $thumbnail-border-width:            $border-width;
>   $thumbnail-border-color:            $gray-300;
>   $thumbnail-border-radius:           $border-radius;
>   $thumbnail-box-shadow:              $box-shadow-sm;
>   ```

Comment: But, if we add css style to image like you said, then the page is not getting responsive.

Comment: Your question: `I need to set the image width and height`.  The answer: `style="height:200px; width:200px;"`.  It sounds like you *WANT* `img-fluid`. It means bootstrap will automatically resize the image for you, based on screen dimensions.  But then trying to "second guess" Bootstrap by overriding the height/width yourself... would just defeat the whole point of using img-fluid in the first place.  Please review the Bootstrap link above, and look here: https://linuxhint.com/bootstrap-image-resize.  I hope that helps ... at least a little bit...